# keyboardWillShowNotification called twice when dismissed

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios12

I've subscribed to `keyboardWillShowNotification` and `keyboardWillHideNotification` to move around my UI. I've noticed that when I dismiss the keyboard by tapping the "Go" button, `keyboardWillShowNotification` is called twice (thus reseting some of my constraints) however if dismiss by hitting return on the keyboard (MacBook) then it's not called twice.

How can I avoid it being called twice? Why is this behaviour even there? I can't find any mention of it (lots of references to it being called twice with input views...etc) but never when being dismissed.

Here's my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardNotification(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWasDismissed(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil) 
}
```

and...

```
@objc func keyboardNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
        guard
            let animationDuration = notification.userInfo?["UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey"] as? Double,
            let animationCurve = notification.userInfo?["UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey"] as? NSNumber,
            let frameEnd = notification.userInfo?["UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey"] as? CGRect,
            let frameBegin = notification.userInfo?["UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey"]
            else {
                print("No userInfo recived from NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow")
                return
        }
        print("WILL SHOW")

        let margin = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        constraintsWhenKeyboardVisible = [
                            boxOffice.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margin.leadingAnchor),
                            boxOffice.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margin.trailingAnchor),
                            boxOffice.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margin.bottomAnchor),
                            boxOffice.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -(frameEnd.height + 50))
                        ]
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(boxOfficeFinalConstraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraintsWhenKeyboardVisible)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration,
                       delay: TimeInterval(0),
                       options: UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: animationCurve.uintValue),
                       animations: {
                        self.boxOffice.answerField.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
                        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        },
                       completion: nil)
    }


@objc func keyboardWasDismissed(notification: NSNotification) {
        guard
            let animationDuration = notification.userInfo?["UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey"] as? Double,
            let animationCurve = notification.userInfo?["UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey"] as? NSNumber
            else {
                print("No userInfo recived from NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow")
                return
        }
        print("WILL HIDE")
        //print(notification)
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(self.constraintsWhenKeyboardVisible)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(self.boxOfficeFinalConstraints)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration,
                       delay: TimeInterval(0),
                       options: UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: animationCurve.uintValue),
                       animations: {
                        self.boxOffice.answerField.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner]
                        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        },
                       completion: nil)

    }
```

Comment: show how you subscribed for notification and where?

Comment: I've added observers to viewDidLoad - I also tried viewDidAppear but no change

Comment: try registering in viewWillAppear() after calling super.viewWillAppear()

Comment: Did you find some solution for this?

Comment: See my Answer below. I was adding constraints with each notifications, I fixed it by simple changing the existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't solved the issue of keyboardWillShowNotification being posted when Return is hit on the iOS keyboard simulator but not on the hardware keyboard in the simulator, but I have modified my code so that when the keyboard is shown I don't add constraints, I simply modify the constant of the constraint using the height from the keyboard notification. This has solved it.

```
boxOfficeWhenKeyboardVisible[3].constant = -(frameEnd.height + 50)
```